# How write a correct SQL request from Excel to Access without error?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access-2010

I want to run an SQL query from excel to Access as shown below.
When I run the code, I get an "Incompatible data type in criterion expression" error. Do you have a tip, please, to get me out of this?

Regards

```vb
Sub test()
  Dim myDate As Date
  Dim myCUID As String
  Dim i As Long
  Dim cnt As Object, rst As Object

  Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  Set cnt = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

  strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ATD_monitoring_basePro.accdb';"

  'Open connection to the database
  cnt.Open strConnection

  'Begin transaction processing
  cnt.BeginTrans

  myDate = WorkSheets("Bla").Range("A1").Value
  myCUID = "XXXX1234"
  sqlCmd = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE Date= '" & myDate & "' AND CUID='" & myCUID & "';"
  rst.Open sqlCmd, cnt

  'Close the ADO objects
  cnt.Close
  Set rst = Nothing
  Set cnt = Nothing
  On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: maybe `WHERE [Date]`  Also, what is myDate being returned as?

Comment: In Access "Date" field is also string? from my view you probably in Access have normal date format, and now you trying to compare string vs date.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav. myDate retrieves a value from a range with the Date category of type "*14/03/2012". The problem arose when I changed the text range to Date. it worked well before

Comment: @Bankeris. In Access Date field is also in Date format not in String.

Answer (score 1):

In Access, dates must be wrapped with `#` and formatted `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Try this:

```
sqlCmd = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE [Date]= #" & _
          Format(myDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "# AND CUID='" & myCUID & "';"

Debug.Print sqlCmd
```

Comment: Many thanks. it works much better like that. This one I will remember well.